# Order by Numeric then alpha

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM locations ORDER BY cast(X as decimal), X, Y
```

This code prints like this:

```
ADMIN
CAFE
CDC
CMAT
1 
1.5
2
10
10.5
18
```

I am looking for a way to put the alpha on the bottom and the numeric on top in the same order as shown.

```
1 
1.5
2
10
10.5
18
ADMIN
CAFE
CDC
CMAT
```

Comment: I've not tested it so adding it as a comment. Have you tried, `SELECT * FROM locations ORDER BY X, cast(X as decimal), Y`?

Comment: No X makes messes with alpha and it's still on top

Answer (score 1):

Almost there

```
$sql = "(SELECT *,cast(X as decimal) FROM locations WHERE X REGEXP '^[0-9]') UNION ALL
    (SELECT *,X FROM locations WHERE X REGEXP '^[a-z,A-Z]')
    ORDER BY X";
```

Numbers on top but 1,1.5,10,10.5,18,2

```
    instead of 1, 1.5, 2, 10, 10.5, 18
```

Alpha on bottom is in order ADMIN, CAFE, CDC,CMAT

Answer (score 0):

you can use union of 2 queries with regexp one query to match numbers only and order them in ascending manner and in second query just get data which is non numeric

```
(SELECT * FROM locations 
where x REGEXP '^[0-9]'
order by cast(x as decimal)
 )
union
(SELECT * FROM locations 
where x REGEXP '^[0-9]' = 0
order by x
)
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddc356/1)

Another solution would be first order by casting and then use a subselect and order it by regexp

```
select * from (
select * from  locations 
order by cast(x as decimal) , x
  ) t
order by x REGEXP '^[0-9]' desc
```

### [`Demo 2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddc356/9)

Comment: $sql = "(SELECT * FROM locations where X REGEXP '^[0-9]' order by cast(X as decimal) )
union
(SELECT * FROM locations where X REGEXP '^[0-9]' = 0 order by X)";

Am I wrong? Numbers on top, alpha on bottom, both out of order.

Comment: @user3613148 this what you asked for *I am looking for a way to put the alpha on the bottom and the numeric on top* and here is the [*`demo`*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddc356/1) numbers on top and alpha on bottom right ?

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid It looks perfect in here but not on mine.  I must be doing something wrong and not seeing it.

Comment: INSERT INTO 'locations' ('location_id', 'X', 'Y', ) VALUES
(332, 'ADMIN', 'PLC')
etc.


$sql_result = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
echo "<td align='center' width='100'>" . $row['X'] . "</td>";   
echo "<td align='center' width='100'>" . $row['Y'] . "</td>";   
}

Shows this:

ADMIN
CAFE
CDC
CMAT
1 
1.5
2
10
10.5
18

Now I try 
$sql = "(SELECT * FROM locations where X REGEXP '^[0-9]' order by cast(X as decimal)) union (SELECT * FROM locations where X REGEXP '^[0-9]' = 0 order by X)";

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "(SELECT * FROM locations WHERE X REGEXP '^[1-9][0-9]' 
   ORDER BY cast(X as decimal), X, Y)
   UNION ALL
   (SELECT * FROM locations WHERE X REGEXP '^[a-z,A-Z]') ORDER BY X, Y";
```

Adding [1-9] to the REGEXP makes it work.

Comment: Please don't add duplicate answers add some new solution if you have other wise delete it